# Flexbox Content Align

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been struggling to make the content within the flexbox items align equally.

[image]

As you can see, the three of them are equal height, but what I want to achieve is make all the paragraphs align/scale with the other ones.

```css
.grid-chefs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.cfcol {
  width: 32%;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.cfcol>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.cfcol>h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-chefs">
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Smith</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Smith Doe</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to make that happen you have to add min-height to your h3 tags

Comment: All the paragraphs aligned well. Can you clarify how you want to align them?

Comment: That is not possible with flexbox and that HTML structure. Those `h3` elements have no relation to each other that this could be based on.

Comment: There is NO method in CSS to align element that do not share a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented before you have to add min-height to your h3 tags

Else consider reducing the font size of your headings

Try this

```css
        .grid-chefs {
        display: flex;
        width: 33%;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin:auto;
    }

    .cfcol {
        width: 32%;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .cfcol > img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100px;
    }

    .cfcol > h3{
        font-size: 22px;
        min-height:75px;
        display:flex; 
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid-chefs">
            <div class="cfcol">
                <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
                <h3>John Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cfcol">
                <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
                <h3>John Smith</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cfcol">
                <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
                <h3>John Smith Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also a working codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVqrYL

Comment: Happy to help you anytime :D

Answer (score 1):

CSS Flexbox doesn't allow you to align items inside separate parents. You could work around it by using the new CSS Grid layout with `display: contents` for the columns but the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) for the latter is still quite far from satisfactory.

For now you need to have fixed height for your images and headings if you want to align your paragraphs in a browser compatible manner.

```css
.grid-chefs {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.cfcol {
  width: 32%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: contents;
}

.cfcol>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.cfcol>h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-chefs">
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Smith</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cfcol">
    <img src="img/chef.jpg" />
    <h3>John Smith Doe</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```